# IPTABLES comment: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: centos, kernel, iptables

Faced with error when adding new rule with 'comment':

```
# iptables -I INPUT 1 --source 66.***.***.78 -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Some"
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Without comment - works normally.

Using **CentOS** 6.5, kernel 2.6.32

But same command works on other box, with same OS.

Both have same modules:

```
# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
icmp
state
udplite
udp
tcp

 # lsmod | grep ip
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9506  8
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter          2793  1
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
ipt_LOG                 5845  0
ipt_REJECT              2351  5
ip6t_REJECT             4628  2
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8337  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         11156  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack           79758  3 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2889  1
ip6_tables             18732  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  318183  17 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
```

Comment: Shouldn't the /proc/net/ip_tables_matches file have 'comment' as one of its lines?

Comment: @Sree I also thought about this, but - on second box there is no such line too, but same command works...

Answer (score 0):

check whether the system has ip assigned on the port that you are configuring.
easy way is to remove the network configuration (`ifcfg-eth*`) file and configure newly so that the issue gets resolved.